# UILabel sizeToFit with relative font size not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel, drawrect

If I have a multiline string which I put in a UILabel, 
set the font size relative to the bounds of the view, 
and then I call `sizeToFit`,
all of which happens in `drawRect:`,
it perfectly sizes my label. 
Once `drawRect:` is called again because of an orientation change,
it screws up the size needed to fit.

`self.bounds.width` is much bigger than the label needs in all cases.

code:

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {
    var label = UILabel()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.contentMode = .Redraw
        addSubview(label)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let string = "this is line 1\r\nand\r\nthis is line 3"
        label.numberOfLines = 3
        label.text = string
        label.font = label.font.fontWithSize(self.bounds.width / 30)
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        label.sizeToFit()

        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        label.center = self.center
    }
}
```

initially everything looks OK:

[image]

But when my bounds change because of a different orientation:

[image]

Any ideas what am I doing wrong here? By the way, it's the width that somehow doesn't want to grow. because if I set `label.numberOfLines = 0`, it does grow, but only in height.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that you need to set the `frame.size.width` and / or the `frame.size.height` of the `UILabel` to zero before calling `sizeToFit` again, like:

`label.frame.size.width = 0`

or

`label.frame = CGRectZero`

Like that it resizes properly again, respecting the `numberOfLines`.